# GPGPU CUDA debug server

Tags: cuda

I have access to a server machine, with 3 CUDA enabled GPUs in it, and I would like to use NVidia Parallel Nsight, to remotly debug on the machine.
This works just find.

Now, is it possibble, to start another debug session (possibbly by another developer), on the same machine, but on another GPGPU?

Is it possibble, to do this, if I use gdb on linux?

Thanks,
krisy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Krisy, yes this is possible.

However this case/scenario that you mentioned has not been actively tested internally by the Nsight team yet. I tried this our real quick on a system with a similar setup as the one you mentioned and I was able to debug 2 different instances of CUDA app simulataneously (provided each app runs on a different unique device that is not connected to any output display).

The stability of this is not guaranteed. From what I've tried so far, this worked for me and it should work in theory as well but there were instances where I experienced sluggish behavior on my system.

For other developers who are interested to know more about this, please take a look at: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=201211